# Comparing expressions exactly

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

Suppose I have two expressions; call them $A$ and $B$.  The following values of $A$ and $B$ are good examples for my question...

$$
A = \pi e^2\\
B = \pi^2 e
$$

Is there a method to determine the truth of comparisons such as $A \ge B$, $A \lt B$, etc?  Especially, I want to ensure that exactness is preserved if possible, so I'd like to avoid converting $A$ and $B$ to numbers.

Comment: No general method, no.

Comment: In this particular case, we can at least factorize:
$$A\ge B \iff A-B\ge0 \iff \pi e(e-\pi)\ge0 \iff e-\pi\ge0$$

Comment: @Tharsis But can I then decide whether $e - \pi \ge 0$?

Comment: @gh403 Use the definitions of the quantities $e$ and $\pi$ to replace them by finite or infinite sums, products, and the like, and then try to simplify once more. Continue (if possible) until the order of the remaining quantities is known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I believe I can be a bit more specific. Even if the number is the result of using integers,  addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and the placement of square root signs anywhere, there is no canonical way of writing this number. Meaning there is no evident way of telling whether it is positive or negative: a certain amount of cleverness in squaring sides, gathering on one side, etc. will be required. Thus, if we take the square root of what we have so far, we cannot entirely be sure the result is real.

Comment: Suppose my program (for it *is* a program I'm writing ;) has its own notion of "canonical form."  Is it possible once I have both $A$ and $B$ in canonical form?

Comment: @gh403, first, tell me whether $$ 18991028052879952877717003280980106896077255885649556410 -  317799749249667142896491448615083010692333748314716137 \cdot \sqrt{3571}  $$  is positive or negative, then we can discuss it further.

Comment: Then $$  3026807861414232601576476947093931340883926646932707209616924 -   27015380505739903416049453225901131788373049465835213058397 \cdot \sqrt{12553}  
 $$

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense.